# Need to learn some javascript codes!! Would you help me?

Tags: javascript, animation, live, code-snippets

It can be a simple question here for many of you but for me it's a tough one!! 
Anyways, I'd like to know why **pos+=1;** is used instead of **pos=+1;** in **javascript**..when we go to make an animation?? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pos += 1` will increment the variable `pos` by 1, and return it.

`pos = +1` is the same as saying `pos = 1`. The plus is redundant.

See it in action with this simple script:

```js
pos1 = 10;
pos2 = 10;

pos1 += 1;
pos2 =+ 1;

console.log('pos1', pos1);
console.log('pos2', pos2);
```

Comment: Aww!! I see!! Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

The logic is a little opaque if you jam the characters up against one another.  + and = are separate operators, one for addition, the other for assignment.  Put together, += is an operator in its own right, the post-increment operator.  In the first example, what you have is the following:

```
value += 1
```

Which is to say, *increment value by 1.* In the second example, it actually looks like this:

```
value = +1 // Identical to value = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

syntax evaluate like right to left assignment. so `pos=+1` is like assigning positive value 1 to variable `pos`. but if we want to add then we use `pos+=1` means add 1 to `pos` and assign to `pos`

Comment: you can think in anther way what is you want to subtract negative value `pos=--1` in this case `--` is operator and set 1 into 0.